# How redirect to login after cookie time expired c# owin?

Tags: c#, owin, identity

I hope you are very well, my code is the following:

```
                    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
             AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/Login"),                
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnResponseSignIn = context =>
                {
                    context.Properties.AllowRefresh = true; context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1);
                },
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)
                    )
            },
            SlidingExpiration = true,
            ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)                 
        });
```

With the previos code, the app dont redirect to the login. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Apps redirect to login any time you hit an Authorize'd endpoint with a missing or expired cookie.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but with the previos code, only redirect to login after the user generates a postback, but no redirect automatically to Login  after the ExpireTimeSpan finish, How i can set up the app to redirect automatically? thanks a lot.